# My loop never ends...and I dont understand why. Any ideas?

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, while-loop

I am trying to find out why my loop never ends. I am trying to take two numbers, start with the smallest, and keep divid by 4 until it reaches 0.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main
{
    int x, y, answer = 0;

    cout << "dude enter two numbers " << endl;
    cin >> x >> y;

    //this is trouble statement
    for (int num = x; num <= y; num++) 
    { 
        while (num != 0)

            answer = num / 4;
            cout << answer << " ";
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The inner `while` is the problem. You loop while `num` is not 0, but you never change it. You only change `answer`.

Comment: how would you change the code? Thanks for the advice!

Comment: The code above doesn't even compile with unbalanced braces, AFAICT. What's the real code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The condition `while (num != 0)` is the problem.

As, you are not modifying `num` in the `while` loop, hence the value of `num` would never change.
Hence, the infinite loop.

A few changes in your code will suffice :

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;    
int main()
{
    int x, y, answer = 0;
    cout << "dude enter two numbers " << endl;
    cin >> x >> y;
    for (int num = x; num <= y; num++) 
    { 
        //Created a temporary variable.
        int temp = num;
        //All operations on the temporary variable.
        while (temp != 0)
        {
            temp = temp/ 2;
            cout << temp << " ";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Pressing that green little tick would be helpful for me too. :)

Comment: It's interesting to see the logical errors we make, though small can alter the results drastically. The guideline in this regard is to check the loops variable to see if it meets the exit condition sometime in the future during the course of  iterations. It is a golden rule in "Safety and Dependability" of programs to ensure that your program is in fact doing what you intend it to do. :)